# Graphical distortions on high res / high refresh rate monitor

Tags: graphics

Ever since upgrading to a 1440p 144hz monitor, Ubuntu has been displaying strange graphical distortions. This is one example:

[image: graphical distortions on Ubuntu]

This doesn't happen on Windows, therefore I think this is an OS-specific or software problem and not a hardware defect. It also didn't happen with my old 1080p monitor, and I haven't changed any settings since changing monitors (besides upping the refresh rate).

I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this, so any help is appreciated.

**Note**: I had to take a photo with my phone because screenshotting it didn't capture the distortions.

This also seems to happen spontaneously. Sometimes it works fine, other times the graphical distortions appear. I haven't been changing any settings, so I don't know why it randomly occurs some times and not others.

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 just added it

Comment: Note: I recently tried reinstalling drivers for my GPU and this didn't work. I also updated to Ubuntu 19.10, this didn't change anything either.

Comment: Could you try testing limiting the resolution and framerate separately to see if it happens with only one or the other? `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 60.00` and `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144.00` (change your output accordingly)

Comment: @Vardogor the 144hz refresh rate seems to be causing the issue (not the resolution)

Comment: @Crabtree I'm not using an adapter, just a DisplayPort to mini DisplayPort cable. This is the only cable that supports 144Hz, therefore I'm not going to use another cable (nor will it be able to test this problem because it'll be at 60Hz). If the cable was the problem this would also be causing issues in Windows.

Comment: Are you using any overclocking software by chance? I had an issue similar to yours long ago because I was tweaking my GPU clock speeds.

Comment: @Crabtree nope, nothing is overclocked